# Stuck with a simple awk script

Tags: awk

I'm learning a bit of awk with a basic users.txt including names, ages and countries. The fact is I'm not being able to construct a ternary operator one-liner.

This is the file to work with:

```
John 23 Italy
David 18 Spain
Sarah 21 Germany
Dan 42 Germany
Brian 50 England
```

And this is my idea of the one-liner based on if-else condition:

```
awk '{$1 == "David" ? print "$1" : "Not David"}' users.txt
```

I achieved to work an if-else awk script but I'm trying to do it with this one-liner and I'm constantly getting syntax errors hence I'm not sure if I can do it this way. (awk is mandatory, please)

Comment: @anubhava Thanks! the condition works, no syntax error but it prints literally a $1 and not the actual name, is it possible to use the $1 and not implicitly "David"?

Comment: It should be: `awk '{print ($1 == "David" ? $1 : "Not David")}' users.txt`

Comment: Yes, correct! it was that, the print was literally getting the "$1" like \$1 so it was not detecting the variable. So, to understand correctly the syntax the print has to have condition implicitly or otherwise it doesn't work. I was confused on the order because the if-else statement works different.

Comment: in a shell (eg, `bash`) it is recommended that you double quote variable references (eg, `"$1"`); in `awk` you do not (double) quote variables nor do you (double) quote field references (eg, `$1`); you're using shell syntax (`print "$1"`) when you should be using `awk` syntax (ie, `print $1` - no double quotes); in your code (`print "$1"`) you are telling `awk` to print the literal string `$1`